# Tests pass when ran one by one but test suite throws an error

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test the behavior of a form component. I have the following test suite:

```
import {createLocalVue, mount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import formDiscovery from '../pages/Discovery'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import VeeValidate, {Validator} from 'vee-validate'
import * as moduleContactInfos from '../store/contactInfos'
import * as moduleCompanyInfos from '../store/companyInfos'
import fr from 'vee-validate/dist/locale/fr'

let wrapper, store
beforeEach(() => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  localVue.use(Vuex)
  localVue.use(VeeValidate)
  Validator.localize('fr', fr)
  localVue.use(Buefy)
  store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      contactInfos: moduleContactInfos,
      companyInfos: moduleCompanyInfos
    }
  })
  wrapper = mount(formDiscovery, {
    localVue,
    store,
    stubs: ['router-link']
  });
})

/*
    This test suite tests if a field is shown when the user selects a specific option in a select input
    and that this field is hidden when any other option is selected
*/
describe("field 'more details'", () => {
  it("is shown when the 'Other: specify' select option is selected", () => {
    wrapper.vm.$data.choiceCompanyInfos = 'Other: specify'
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      const input = wrapper.find('#moreDetails')
      expect(input.isVisible()).toBeTruthy()
    })
  })

  it('is hidden when a valid select option is selected', () => {
    wrapper.vm.$data.choiceCompanyInfos = 'A valid select option'
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      const input = wrapper.find('#moreDetails')
      expect(input.isVisible()).toBeFalsy()
    })
  })
})

/*
    This test suite tests is veevalidate generates the correct error messages
*/
describe('vee validate', () => {

  it('adds an error when a required form field is empty', async () => {
    const input = wrapper.find('[name="phone"]')
    expect(input.exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.vm.errors.count()).toBe(0)
    store.commit('contactInfos/updatePhone', '')
    await wrapper.vm.$validator.validate('phone')
    expect(wrapper.vm.errors.count()).toBe(1)
  })

  it('adds an error when the phone has an invalid format', async () => {
    const input = wrapper.find('[name="phone"]')
    expect(input.exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.vm.errors.count()).toBe(0)
    store.commit('contactInfos/updatePhone', '6156') // Valid format : 0?[0-9]{9}
    await wrapper.vm.$validator.validate('phone')
    expect(wrapper.vm.errors.count()).toBe(1)
    expect(wrapper.vm.errors.first('phone').indexOf('invalid')).toBeGreaterThan(-1) // The error message must contains 'invalid'
  })
})
```

The component under test contains multiple nested child components (form field containing buefy label and buefy input, etc)
It also contains two nuxt-link components.

When I run a test alone, it works. However, if a try to run a describe suite or the entire file, I have the following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$scopedSlots' of undefined
    at updateChildComponent (.\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.common.dev.js:4100:27)
    at prepatch (.\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.common.dev.js:3128:5)
```

I tried to recreate the store for each test, to create a new instance of localVue for each test. Nothing work. Any ideas ?

Comment: wondering it you found how to sort this out, I'm currently in the same situation as yours..

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same error and got it resolved using `sync: false` while mounting your component. So in your case just follow the below code.

```
 wrapper = mount(formDiscovery, {
    sync: false,
    localVue,
    store,
    stubs: ['router-link']
 });
```